# Jquery - Mount Drag and Drop items from created json

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Im using the script from this codepen [https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/mgNVpx][1]

I can already save the result from a JSON (created by the script).

Problem: I need to build it back with the saved data.

It generates a JSON like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "zone_1",
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10,
    "width": 426,
    "height": 426,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "aplicativos",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "aplicativos"
        },
        {
            "id": "arbitros",
            "x": 142,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "arbitros"
        },
        {
            "id": "bola-na-rede",
            "x": 284,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "bola-na-rede"
        },
        {
            "id": "sem-categoria",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 142,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "sem-categoria"
        },
        {
            "id": "crochet",
            "x": 142,
            "y": 142,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "crochet"
        },
        {
            "id": "estudos",
            "x": 284,
            "y": 142,
            "width": 142,
            "height": 142,
            "col": 4,
            "text": "estudos"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Now, i need to build it back when loading it.

As obvious i have loaded it into a variable called zone_coord;

```
<?php if (trim($valorEstiloPortal)<>'') {?>




    var zone_coord =  <?php echo $valorEstiloPortal;?>;


    
    <?php } else { ?>
        
        
var zone_coord = [
{
  id: 'zone_1',
  x: 25,
  y: 25,
  width: 450,
  height: 450,
  children: [] 
}
];


<?php } ?>

var items = zone_coord[0].children.length;
```

And at the end of the script i have made a looping:

```
if (items>0){
    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        //removo os que eu tenho salvo aqui para não ficar na lista de categorias a serem incluidas. Senao eu poderia colocar duas vezes.
        var nomeCategoria = $.trim(zone_coord[0].children[i].id);
        if ($("#"+nomeCategoria).length !== 0) {
            $("#"+nomeCategoria).remove();
        }
        $("#zone_1").append('<div id="'+zone_coord[0].children[i].id+'" class="widgets ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable inZone" style="position: relative; z-index: 7; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:'+zone_coord[0].children[i].width+'px; height: '+zone_coord[0].children[i].height+'px; min-width: '+zone_coord[0].children[i].width+'px; min-height: '+zone_coord[0].children[i].height+'px;"><div class="widget-inner"><div class="widget-txt text-center">'+zone_coord[0].children[i].id+'</div></div><div class="remove_widget text-center" title="Return this widget to the default grid container."><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><i class="fa fa-arrows-v resize-icon"></i><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div>');
    }
 

}
```

The big problem is that i cant even resize those elements. Does anyone have any idea how i can solve this?